# How do I add a query parameter to a Play redirect?

Tags: scala, url, playframework, playframework-2.3

If I construct a [Play](http://playframework.com/) redirect like `Redirect(routes.RegistrationController.register())`, how can I add a query parameter to the URL I'm redirecting to?

For example, I'd like a URL like this: `/register?token=1234`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do `Redirect(routes.RegistrationController.register().url + "?token=1234")`.

Or, supposing your route declares `token` as an optional parameter with the route declaration `GET /register @controllers.RegistrationController(token: Option[Int])`, then you could do `Redirect(routes.RegistrationController.register(Some(1234)))`.

There are various variations to how you could set this up. You may want to see the [Play router documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.6/ScalaRouting).